# Format a string into regular time not military

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ipad

I am trying to format a string into regular time not military time. How would I do this.

```
if ([components hour] == 0 &&
        [components minute] == 0 &&
        [components second] == 0){

        result.detailTextLabel.text = 
        [NSString stringWithFormat:
         @"%02ld/%02ld/%02ld - %02ld/%02ld/%02ld All Day",
         (long)[components month],
         (long)[components day],
         (long)[components year],
         (long)[components1 month],
         (long)[components1 day],
         (long)[components1 year]];

    } else {
        result.detailTextLabel.text = 
        [NSString stringWithFormat:
         @"%02ld/%02ld/%02ld at %02ld:%02ld - %02ld:%02ld",

         (long)[components month],
         (long)[components day],
         (long)[components year],
         (long)[components hour],
         (long)[components minute],
         (long)[components1 hour],
         (long)[components1 minute]];

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by normal time? Give examples

Comment: 1:23pm   12:20am     3:23pm     8:31am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDateComponents *components = /* ... */;
NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents: components];
NSString *string = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate: date dateStyle: NSDateFormatterNoStyle timeStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
```

This is a lot simpler and it auto-localizes the result string.

Comment: Right. `NSDateFormatterShortStyle` for time gives you XX:XX AM/PM and `NSDateFormatterNoStyle` for date doesn't show the date.

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct way to do it.  It will format the time according to the user's locale and preferences — so in Germany or France it will use 24 hour time, and in the US it will use AM/PM.

```
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle]; // Full time with seconds, no TZ
[fmt setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle]; // No date
NSDate *now = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
NSLog(@"%@", [fmt stringFromDate:now]);
```

If you try to implement date / time formatting yourself, you will only enrage the users that changed their system preferences and those who live in other countries.  Do the right thing, use a library function.

Comment: You didn't `-release` your `NSDateFormatter` instance.

Comment: I'm assuming that you know how to do that.

Comment: Except the OP didn't ask for time formatted according to the user's preferences.  He asked for a way to convert from 24h time to 12h time.

Comment: @aroth "Spirit" versus "letter" of the question, I suppose.  If we always answered questions with a narrow interpretation of what people asked, civilization would grind to a halt.

Comment: wait i tried to put it in but it didn't work where does it go and how do i call it from [NSString stringWithFormat:
             @"%02ld/%02ld/%02ld at %02ld:%02ld - %02ld:%02ld",

Comment: The call `[fmt stringFromDate:now]` returns an `NSString`.